# IE8 gradient and Image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to create a span with a gradient and a background image to the right. Now I have been searching for quite some time now and have been adding pieces of code together. Everything was working until I tested for IE8. Answered questions related to my problem that I found on stack overflow are still not working for me. here is the code:

```
background: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url(../images/selectArrows.png) center center no-repeat; /* fallback */
background-image: url(../images/selectArrows.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#ededed)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url(../images/selectArrows.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ededed); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image: url(../images/selectArrows.png),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ededed); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url(../images/selectArrows.png),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ededed); /* IE10 */
background-image: url(../images/selectArrows.png),      -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ededed); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: url(../images/selectArrows.png),         linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ededed); /* W3C */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#FFFFFF", endColorstr="#ededed",GradientType=0 ), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../images/selectArrows.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 100% 50%;
```

Comment: Try splitting out the two DXImageTransforms into two filters; I'm not sure if you can have a comma there outside the parentheses.

Comment: First filter doesn't work either when I split them up in two separate filters.

Answer (score 0):

I woul recommend you using this awesome background editor: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

You can upload your `selectArrows.png` and import background from it. it will give you the exact css you can use, crossbrowser!

Comment: not exactly what I am looking for, I will find it useful in the future thou.